# How to display html content converted into xaml flowdocument in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, flowdocument

My objective is to display html content in wpf application. I use brwoser control but this always goes on top of window. I search through the net and found a solution to convert the html into a flow document. But my question is how to use the conveted flowdocument in wpf application to show the html content

Please refer the [below article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980334/wpf-webbrowser-3-5-sp1-always-on-top-other-suggestion-to-display-html-in-wpf) as well.

Answer (score 9):

You have several options here:

- You can convert the HTML to a FlowDocument as you described and display that in 
  one of the several [FlowDocument viewer variations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx).
- You can show a [limited subset of HTML directly in a Frame control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617939/wpf-frame-control).
- You can use [Chris Cavanaugh's](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/) new [WPF Chromium WebBrowser
  Control](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/) based on Google's Chrome browser.  This control is a true
  WPF control and will play well in the scenario you described.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host the flow document in e.g. a FlowDocumentPageViewer: